# How can I use date2num?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, datetime, matplotlib

Hello I have this date :

"2018-12-02 22:30:00+01:00"

and I need to convert it with date2num but it does not work because I got 737030.895833

Could you help me please ?

Thank you !

Comment: What is "date2num"?  There is nothing in the standard library nor any package on PyPI by that name.

Comment: It is the following function : https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.date2num

Comment: @jwodder https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.date2num

Comment: Please pick a version of python and remove one of the version tags. Your question is currently very unclear; I happen to use matplotlib but you shouldn't assume that people will automatically know what `date2num` is

Comment: What exactly isn't working?  737030.895833 looks like the correct answer to me.

Comment: Something like "It doesn't work because it gives me <the correct result>" is not understandable. I'd suggest you delete this question and if there is anything unclear, ask specifically about that showing the code you use and clearly state in how far the result is not what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

`date2num` is used mostly in plotting in matplotlib. For example, one can convert a datetime object to string and then to "num" by `date2num`

```
def timestr_to_num(timestr):
    return mdates.date2num(datetime.strptime('0' + timestr if timestr[1] == ':' else timestr, '%I:%M:%S %p'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an older matplotlib version (like 2.2.2), you have to interpret in a different mode the number that you got.

So, if you put the number that you got in an online converter you will think that the conversion is wrong but it isn't. Older Matplotlib versions use a different reference to epoch time. (Look the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wytZj.jpg)).

Answer (score -4):

```
 import time
 import datetime
 s = "02/12/2018"
 time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y/%m/%d/%h/%M/%s").timetuple())
```

Comment: @roganjosh nice edit ,he can print it to see the result or save it .

Comment: I get the impression that the OP wants to convert a string to a date (and then to a number), so this is actually the opposite of what they want.

Comment: For your own understanding, try `print(timeNow)` after the code you've given. It will not give a string-formatting timestamp because `strftime` does not work in place. In any case, that really doesn't apply to `date2num` from the `matplotlib` library.

Comment: @jwodder i edited my answer based on question being "unclear"